# Better way to write @instances.count > 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code:

```
<% if  @states.count > 0 %>  # @states is an active record collection
```

I just feel like there should be a better way to write this.

I am looking for  something like:

```
<% if  @states.not_empty? %>
```

I realize this is tiny change but it would be a welcome cleanup.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want ActiveRecord's `any?`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-any-3F

```
<% if @states.any? %>
    Do stuff here if @states has at least one result
<% end %>
```

Comment: why `any?`? `any?` loops through an enumerable collection and returns true if the predicate passed in the block returns true for **any** element in the collection. The OP wants to test the collection as a whole

Comment: For an `Array` (or specifically, `Enumerable`), yes, but the OP's use of ERb suggests he's maybe working with an ActiveRecord collection. `ActiveRecord::Relation`'s `any?` doesn't require a block, it just checks to see if the collection is empty or not. (Although, `Array`'s version doesn't *require* a block, either.)

Comment: There's a version with a block which will scan the list for matches, but this is optional.

Comment: `any?` on an ActiveRecord collection without a block is literally just `!empty?` - a positive version of the one suggested by @Andy H

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
<% unless @states.empty? %>
```

Answer (score 3):

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class

```
if @states.exists?
```